# Not able to obtain value in view (directive)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an array in the `profile-form.html` directive's controller.
But I am neither able to obtain the value of that array (`all_languages`) nor iterate over it using `ng-options` in the directive. It's simply printing as string. I am new to Angular and maybe doing everything terribly wrong.

**Directive**

```
app.directive("profileForm", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "/static/translatorNgApp/profile-form.html",
        controller: ['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http) {

            this.getCookie = function(name) {
                var cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(cookieValue);
                return cookieValue;
            };

            $scope.csrftoken = this.getCookie('csrftoken');

            $scope.myForm={};
            $scope.all_languages = ['English', 'Hindi'];
            $scope.language_pairs = [];

            $scope.getAllLanguages = function () {
                $http.get('/getAllLanguages'
                ).success(function(response) {
                    // success
                    $scope.all_languages.concat(response);
                }).error(function(response) {
                    // failed
                });
            };

            $scope.submitForm = function() {
                var postData = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/accounts/tprofile/',
                    // headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-Token' : $scope.csrftoken },
                    data: $scope.myForm
                };

                $http(postData)
                    .then(function(response) {
                            // success
                        },
                        function(response) { // optional
                            // failed
                        });
                    console.log("Form submitted");
                // $scope.message = "Sent Successfully 2";
                // console.log(postData);
                console.log(postData);
                console.log($scope.myForm);

            };

            $document.ready(function(){
                console.log("document ready");
                $scope.getAllLanguages();  //This can be commented out for the question's sake.
            });
        }],
        controllerAs: "profileFormCtrl"
    };
});
```

**Directive Template** (profile-form.html)

```
            <div class="form-group" >
                <label for="id_source_language">Source language: </label>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <pre>all_languages = {{all_languages | json}}</pre>
                        <select data-ng-model="source" ng-options="language for language in all_languages" class="form-control" id="id_source_language" name="source_language" placeholder="Source Language" required>
                        </select>
                        <button ng-click="language_pairs.pop($index)" aria-label="Remove">Remove</button>
                        <button ng-click="language_pairs.push({})">Add more pair</button>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
```

Comment: I don't know exactly how it worked but passing `$document` in controller solved the problem.

Comment: why `$document.ready` inside a controller, you shouldn't have that there.instead call `getAllLanguages` method directly at controller end..

Comment: @PankajParkar I followed what you mentioned and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: do you wanted to add me it as an answer with more explanation? I'll do it if you want.. other can also get benefit from it.

Comment: I was just curious. Why didn't my initial code worked? Why was I not able to access the value. It should have been accessible as it should have been in the scope.

Comment: @PankajParkar That would be so wonderful of you, if you could :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `document.ready` event inside a angular directive doesn't make sense to call specific method of scope. Because `document.ready` event has already happened after that event only angular started process page.

Ideally to make your code working state you need to remove `$document.ready(function(){ .... });` code which isn't required there. And as `document.ready` is already accomplished, so the one which you had registered from directive wouldn't get call.